# Writing Apache Arrow dataset in batches in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I'm wondering what the correct approach is to creating an Apache Arrow multi-file dataset as described [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html) in batches. The tutorial explains quite well how to write a new partitioned dataset from data in memory, but is it possible to do this in batches?

My current approach is to simply write the datasets individually, but to the same directory. This *appears* to be working, but I have to imagine this causes issues with the metadata that powers the feature. Essentially, my logic is as follows (pseudocode):

```
data_ids <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567)

# write data in batches
for (id in data_ids) {
  ## assume this is some complicated computation that returns 1,000,000 records
  df <- data_load_helper(id)

  df <- group_by(df, col_1, col_2, col_3)
  arrow::write_dataset(df, "arrow_dataset/", format = 'arrow')
}

# read in data
dat <- arrow::open_dataset("arrow_dataset/", format="arrow", partitioning=c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3"))

# check some data
dat %>%
 filter(col_1 == 123) %>%
 collect()
```

What is the correct way of doing this? Or is my approach correct? Loading all of the data into one object and then writing it at once is not viable, and certain chunks of the data will update at different periods over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Your solution looks pretty reasonable.

There may be one or two issues you run into.  First, if your batches do not all have identical schemas then you will need to make sure to pass in `unify_schemas=TRUE` when you are opening the dataset for reading.  This could also become costly and you may want to just save the unified schema off on its own.

> certain chunks of the data will update at different periods over time.

If by "update" you mean "add more data" then you may need to supply a `basename_template`.  Otherwise every call to `write_dataset` will try and create `part-0.arrow` and they will overwrite each other.  A common practice to work around this is to include some kind of UUID in the `basename_template`.

If by "update" you mean "replace existing data" then things will be a little trickier.  If you want to replace entire partitions worth of data you can use `existing_data_behavior="delete_matching"`.  If you want to replace matching rows I'm not sure there is a great solution at the moment.

This approach could also lead to small batches, depending on how much data is in each group in each data_id.  For example, if you have 100,000 data ids and each data id has 1 million records spread across 1,000 combinations of col_1/col_2/col_3 then you will end up with 1 million files, each with 1,000 rows.  This won't perform well.  Ideally you'd want to end up with 1,000 files, each with 1,000,000 rows.  You could perhaps address this with some kind of occasional compaction step.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer!

By unified schema, do you mean they are all written with the same partitioning or is it the data type of each column?

As for updating data, I mean both inserting and replacing existing records. Thankfully the workflow is such that I can do entire partitions at a time so that seems in line with what you described. Though I'm not entirely sure what `basename_template` does so I'll dig in to that. Thanks again!

Comment: By unified schema I mean a single schema with every column that is in your dataset.  It would only be a problem if each data_id had its own set of columns.  For example, if `data_id=1` yields columns `[a:int32, b:int64, c:int32]` and `data_id=2` yields columns `[b:int64, c:int32, d:string]` then the unified schema would be `[a:int32, b:int64, c:int32, d:string]`

Comment: Gotcha. The schema will always be consistent so this shouldn't be a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I want to try to transition from Rds files to Arrow datasets. From your answer, I assume that there isn't a method to create one big dataset from smaller Rds, without reading them all in memory. I work with observational data, and through the different processing stages the total amount is close to filling my RAM. I want to add new data and create/delete columns. Now, I am not sure that Arrow is suitable for me.

Comment: @athannats I'm not sure which part of my answer led to that conclusion.  In fact, this should be even easier today.  I'm not sure the correct R incantation but the dataset writer supports receiving data incrementally and automatically creating multiple files as needed.  Even if you want to create one giant single-file dataset you shouldn't need to load everything into memory.

Comment: @Pace, thanks for the clarification. Although I believe I am quite experienced with R, after I tried some examples in order to pack a set of my data from data.table/Rds to arrow/parquet I didn't figure the proper way to append data or add columns. Maybe, I am too familiar with data.table workflow, and dplyr way is still a little strange to me. I will give it another try, anyhow.